# the select option value changes for all other select options

Tags: angular, typescript, nebular, angular-template-form

```
  <nb-select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" 
  (click)="getProdDetails(p.ProductName,p.Brand)" ngDefaultControl>
  <nb-option [value]="p.Size" class="text-nowrap" [hidden]="hide">
     {{ p.Size }} : + {{ p.SaleRate | currency: "INR": 'symbol' : 
 '1.0-0'}}
  </nb-option>
  <nb-option class="text-nowrap" [value]="i.Size" *ngFor="let i of 
     prodDetails"[hidden]="!hide">
     {{ i.Size }} : + {{ i.SaleRate |currency: "INR": 'symbol' : 
 '1.0-0'}}
  </nb-option>
  </nb-select>



 .ts code:

  selectedOption: any;
  getData(){
  this.ProdData = [];
 this.commonservice.get('api').subscribe((data) => {
    const temp = data.data["data"];
   // by using for loop i am iterating through each value of array 
   and pushing it in ProdData
    this.ProdData.push(temp);
   )}
   }
 Similarly in <nb-select> the p is getting values from ProdData 
 Array.
 getProdDetails(name,brand){
 this.prodDetails = [];
 this.commonService
  .get(url)
  .subscribe((res) => {
    const temp = res.data["data"];
     )} 
 }
```

Refer to the image below.
In the first `nb-option`, I get the value from the different arrays.
In second `nb-option` I get the value from array defined in
`getProdDetails()` method.
When I click on the option value of 2nd `nb-option` it replaces the
value of all select options with the selected one.

I hope it will help! Also, if I don't use [(ngModel)] it is working fine. but I need to use it to bind the value and use it in my .ts
file. And I want to show the selected item in the select box every time we select an option.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8ANd.png]

Comment: Welcome to S.O. What do you mean by "it replaces the value of all select options with the selected one"? From your posted image it looks like you have sereval `nb-select`s. Is your issue that all `nb-select`s get the same value when you pick an option from one of them?

Comment: Yes exactly, all nb-select gets the same value if I select an option from any one of the 4, plus I also want to bind the value of the selected option for which I used [(ngModel)]. And I am so grateful, you respond.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the code for all your `nb-select` elements. Anyway as a first check, be sure to bind each of them to a different model: `[(ngModel)]="selectedOption"`. If they're all bound to `selectedOption` the selected value will propagate to each of them.

Comment: Can you provide your .ts code? As other's have mentioned, you must have a unique model for each control.